# Product image url as part of collection load

Tags: product, configuration, catalog, collection

Is it possible to have the product image url loaded as part of the product collection?

for examples:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

This doesnt add the image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do it as such:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$backendModel = $collection->getResource()->getAttribute('media_gallery')->getBackend();

foreach($collection as $product){
    $backendModel->afterLoad($product); //adding media gallery to the product object
    var_dump($product->getData()); //you should see media gallery information here now
}
```

This loads the backend model and appends the media gallery attribute for the `$product` in the loop instead of re-loading the entire product model.

Comment: Since this the go-around method for loading the whole product, does it have any set back in performance?

Comment: Using this code, I get `Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null in /srv/ambushco-/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php on line 76`

Whether I call `load()` on the collection or not, it results in the same error.

Answer (score 3):

These worked for me

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('image');

foreach($collection as $product){
    (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image');
    //Or with resize
    (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(200);
}
```

Comment: but what about other images on the same product?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to access the image URL from the product such as:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach ($collection as $product) {
   echo $product->getImageUrl();
}
```

Comment: but what about other images on the same product?